# How to set-up systemd "cron"-like job to work from some user account while it is inactive

Tags: systemd, cron

I have an user "postgres". And I want to run some cron job which should to work under it's account - "postgres". When it's running as a "postgres" then `psql` will automatically connect as a "postgres" user, without any passwords and similar...

I can do it easy with standard cron - just to add a cron job for the user "postgres". How to do it with systemd?

PS. I read that I have to create 2 "units": one for the timer and another one for the "job". But at the time - that the timer can work for active/logged-in users only. Sure, "postgres" user will not log-in. It won't be active. So, is it possible to do it with systemd, and if yes, please, show me how to achieve it.

Comment: `sudo crontab -u postgres -e`

Comment: A common way to run a user's systemd unit even when the user is not logged in is to define it as a system unit. The `User` key in the `Service` stanza tells which user the service runs as. Of course, this requires you to have root privileges on the system. Would this be acceptable to you?

Answer (score 0):

You want user timer unit. See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html

Example https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fdm#Systemd_Timer

Comment: will it work if the user "postgres" never logs in (is not active)?